# Add First name and last name option in newsletter registration popup in magento extension

Tags: magento, newsletter

At the backend of newsletter there are options for first name and last name , but the first name and last name appears only if the customer has signed up, I want to make it for guest as well, and want to add first name and last name in the popup which appears at the start of my landing page.
Can any one help ☺.

Comment: Please give name of extension have you used for registration popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible out of the box. you would need to save the names of a guest somewhere. Maybe you could use some newsletter extentions: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=newsletter&pl=0